# Laravel custom middleware returning guard as false

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware, laravel-guard

I am making a custom authentication in laravel 9 with custom middleware and custom guard, But the guard in my custom middleware returns false, This is my code

```
<?php

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Defaults
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
| reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
| as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
|
*/

'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Guards
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
| Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
| here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| Supported: "session"
|
*/

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ]
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
| sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
| be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
|
| Supported: "database", "eloquent"
|
*/

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
    ]

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Resetting Passwords
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
| than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
| separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
|
| The expire time is the number of minutes that each reset token will be
| considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
| they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
|
*/

'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
        'throttle' => 60,
    ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Password Confirmation Timeout
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
| times out and the user is prompted to re-enter their password via the
| confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
|
*/

'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

This is my kernel

```
    class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
/**
 * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
 *
 * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
 *
 * @var array<int, class-string|string>
 */
protected $middleware = [
    // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
];

/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array<string, array<int, class-string|string>>
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        'throttle:api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
];

/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
 *
 * @var array<string, class-string|string>
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'auth.session' => \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
    'signed' => \App\Http\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,
];
}
```

The middleware is registered as "admin"
This is my middleware which is returning false when i dd the guard gu

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AdminMiddleware
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next){
    dd(Auth::guard('admin')->check());
    // dd('hh');
    if(Auth::guard('admin')->check() ){
       return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect()->route('admin.login');

}
}
```

This is my login controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Admin;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

// use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class AdminLoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Login Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
| redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
| to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
|
*/

// use AuthenticatesUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
// protected function authenticated()
// {
//    return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
// }

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    // $this->middleware('guest:admin')->except('logout');
}

public function showLoginForm()
{
    return view('login');
}

public function adminLogin(Request $request) {
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $credentials = $request->only('email','password');

    $remember_me = $request->has('remember') ? true : false;

    if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($credentials, $remember_me)) {
        // $user = Auth::guard('admin')->user()->id;
        // $user = Admin::find($user);
        // Auth::guard('admin')->login($user);
        return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
    }  

    // dd(Auth::guard('admin')->check());

    return redirect()->route('admin.login')->with('error', 'Email or Password is incorrect!');
}
}
```

And lastly this is my route service provider where i have added the route in the middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiting\Limit;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
 * The path to the "home" route for your application.
 *
 * Typically, users are redirected here after authentication.
 *
 * @var string
 */
public const HOME = '/home';

/**
 * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, and other route configuration.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    $this->configureRateLimiting();

    $this->routes(function () {
        Route::middleware('api')
            ->prefix('api')
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

        Route::middleware('web')
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
        Route::middleware('admin')
            ->prefix('admin')
           ->namespace($this->namespace)
           ->group(base_path('routes/admin.php')); 
    });
}

/**
 * Configure the rate limiters for the application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function configureRateLimiting()
{
    RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
        return Limit::perMinute(60)->by($request->user()?->id ?: $request->ip());
    });
}
}
```

I have tried everything, This is the exact same thing i am using in one of my other projects and it's working which is on laravel 7, But this version is laravel 9 and it's not working here, I have checked the docs, I did not find anything which could relate to this,
Thanks

Comment: 'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
    ] ------add ,

Comment: I have added this in auth.php

Comment: you missed a comma after bracket.

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0):

in your AdminMiddleware can you try using `auth('admin')->check();` instead of `Auth::guard('admin')->check();`

Comment: It is still returning false